# sentinel controlled loop does not work

Tags: c, sentinel

Why wont this sentinel controlled loop work?

I should be able to enter as many names as I would like the when I enter a `-1` it should terminate.

Can someone point me in the proper direction?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char namedata[50];

  int n, count = 0, names = 1;

  while (names > 0)
  {
    printf("Enter family member name:\n");
    scanf("%s", &names);
    printf("name:");
    puts(namedata);

    if (names > 0)
    {
      namedata[count] = names;
      count = count + 1;
    }
  }

  if (strcmp(names, "crystal") == 0)
  {
    printf("crsytal is cool");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &names);` is wrong. `names` is an `int`.

Comment: You use your `names` variable sometimes as number, sometimes as character, sometimes as string.

Comment: May I direct you towards your debugger?

Answer (score 2):

Your program has numerous problems. I'm too lazy to explain them and suggest the fix for them.

I've rewritten your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char namedata[100][50]; /* 2D array of 100x50 bytes size
                               It can hold upto a max of 100 strings
                               each of max 50 bytes */

    char temp[50]; /* temp array to scan input */

    int count = 0, i;

    while (count < 100) /* Loop until there is no more space to store input */
    {

        printf("Enter family member name:\n");
        scanf("%49s", temp); /* Scan in the input (maximum of 49 chars, +1 for '\0') */

        if (strcmp(temp, "-1") == 0) /* If user typed -1 */
        {
            break; /* Break out of the loop */
        }

        /* Otherwise */

        printf("name:");
        puts(temp);        /* Print the input */

        /* Copy input into the last of the location of the array */
        strcpy(nameData[count], temp); 

        /* Increment count */
        count++;  
    }

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) /* Loop in each index of the array where names are stored */
    {
        if (strcmp(namedata[i], "crystal") == 0) /* If a match is found */
        {
            printf("crsytal is cool");
        }
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

If you do not want to have a fixed size here `char namedata[100][50];`, you need to dynamically allocate memory via `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`.

Comment: Cool Guy Thanks!! Question how come the -1 is being added in the array

Comment: -1 is *not* added to the array `nameData`. This is because the input is scanned into `temp`. Then a condition checks if it is `"-1"`. If so, break out of the loop. If not, it prints the input, adds it to the array, and increments `count`.

Answer (score 0):

At least the 1<sup>st</sup> call to

```
puts(namedata);
```

provokes undefined behaviour as `namedata` is used uninitialised, afterwards anything can happen.

Comment: Before that, `scanf("%s", &names);` is UB.

Comment: @CoolGuy: Correct, that's why I worded "*at least*" ... ;-)